# How can I upload a dynamically created Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to create a script dynamically and then upload it as a Google Apps Script.
When I try this, either

1. If I set the mime type correctly the link looks good, but doesn't work (file not found).
2. If I create a text file, that is just what it is - a text file, not a script file.

Do I need to wrap my code in an extra layer so that the editor can work with it?

Thanks

Michael

Comment: Meta programming in Google Apps Script ? I don't think it is possible. The only meta like control you have is over triggers

Answer (score 0):

There's a way I've seen people implement something like this, but do so at your own peril: UrlFetchApp and eval(). You end up having to host the script somewhere else, pulling it back, and hitting eval() on the script somewhere. You may be able to do this via Google Drive sync and the DocList API.

An Apps Script API within Apps Script is something we've heard feedback for and are talking about, FWIW, but don't let this block you from getting what you need done in the meantime.